# Offset date based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I'm not getting my answer right for this query- Year 2061 is seemingly improper. Convert every year which are < 70 to 19XX instead of 20XX

My data frame date column - 2061-01-01,2061-01-02 ,2061-01-03...

required answer - 1961-01-01,1961-01-02,1961-01-03...

myanswer-1983-05-06 19:59:05.224192,1983-05-07 19:59:05.224192,1983-05-08 19:59:05.224192.....

my code(dataframe name is data)

```
for i in  pd.DatetimeIndex(data['DATE']).year:
    if i<2000:
        data['DATE']=data.DATE+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out:

```
from datetime import datetime , timedelta
data['DATE'] = data.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['DATE'], "%Y-%m-%d") - timedelta(days=100*365+25), axis = 1)
```

data will result in:

```
    DATE
0   1961-01-01
1   1961-01-02
2   1961-01-03
```

Comment: hey, it is giving me error -strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

Comment: could you share the raw data or the value including "data"?

Comment: hey thanks, Thanks for your time ,i got the solution                                                                    data["DATE"] = np.where(pd.DatetimeIndex(data["DATE"]).year < 2000,data.DATE,data.DATE - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100))

Comment: sure, man.. but on clicking it showing me- Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.